# Hide/Unhide viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-view

just an really simple question: How can I *hide/unhide* an `viewpager` in android?

So I just tried the following:

`viewpager.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` -> This works great

`viewpager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` -> This doesn't work

How can I get my `viewpager` visible again?

BR

Comment: Can you please show us some code? It will be easier for us to find the problem.

Comment: well...i've found my mistake (stupid typingerror). Thanks anyway! :)